# Add to regedit path with whitespace and special characters

Tags: pandas, windows, dataframe, cmd, regedit

i am trying to add a script to my right-click that opens Excel files in python pandas.

in computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT*\shell\Open in Pandas\command

The problem is that my username contains a é character and a whitespace.

"C:\Users\André Hermansson\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe"

When i try to use my new right-click script it breaks because 'c/users/andré' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

this is not the full path and it's breaking right by the whitespace.

Can i add the path with whitespace? do i have to create another admin account to change the name of this one? any tips?

Comment: The full regedit path is the following: 
"C:\Users\André Hermansson\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe" "C:\dev\openinpd.py" "%1"

Comment: Post your .reg file

Comment: The simple solution is executing in a command prompt window `reg ADD "HKCR\*\shell\Open in Pandas\command" /f /ve /t REG_EXPAND_SZ /d "\"^%LOCALAPPDATA^%\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe\" \"%1\""`. The same command line for usage in a batch file is: `%SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe ADD "HKCR\*\shell\Open in Pandas\command" /f /ve /t REG_EXPAND_SZ /d "\"%%LOCALAPPDATA%%\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe\" \"%%1\""` See also the predefined list of [Windows Environment Variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable#Windows) output on running `set` in a cmd window.

Comment: The command __REG__ adds to the Windows registry the registry value of type `REG_EXPAND_SZ` (zero terminated string with environment variable reference to expand first) with the string value `"%LOCALAPPDATA%\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe" "%1"`. The double quotes are necessary because of the fully qualified file name of Python after expansion of the variable reference contains a space character. The double quotes around the file/folder name passed to Python for which the placeholder `%1` is in the command line are necessary because of the same reason.

Comment: The solution above works! Thanks!